# Feige–Fiat–Shamir identification scheme: Question about a part of the ZK protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir

My question (at the bottom) is in regards to the part of the protocol where the Verifier challenges the Prover by sending a bit `b` where `b = 0` or `b = 1`.

### Example for context

**One Time Setup**

```
p = 3  
q = 5  
n = 15  
privKey = 8 (co-prime to n)  
pubKey = privKey^2 mod n ⇒ 64 mod 15 = 4
```

> *At this point, the verifier knows:*
>   `n = 15`
>   `pubKey = 4`

**Protocol: The following is repeated t times**

1. Prover selects a random number < n
   `randNum = 11`
2. Prover computes x as follows and sends x to Verifier
   `x = randNum^2 mod n ⇒ 121 mod 15 = 1`
3. Verifier chooses a bit, `b = 0` or `b = 1`, and sends it to Prover as a challenge
4. Prover computes `(privKey^b • randNum) mod n` as a response

> *By choosing a bit* `b = 0` *or* `b = 1` *the Verifier chooses to see either:*
>   **Case 1**
>   *b = 0:* `randNum mod n ⇒ 11 mod 15 = 11` *(if `randNum` is < `n`, verifier will receive `randNum`)*
>   **OR Case 2**
>   *b = 1:*`(randNum • privKey) mod n ⇒ 88 mod 15 = 13`

**Case 1:** `b = 0`
As a response from Prover, Verifier receives: `11`
Verifier computes:

```
11^2 mod 15 = (x • pubKey^b) mod n  
11^2 mod 15 = (1 • 4^0) mod 15  
121 mod 15  = 1 mod 15  
1 = 1 //passes the test
```

**Case 2:** `b = 1`
As a response from Prover, Verifier receives: `13`
Verifier computes:

```
13^2 mod 15 = (x • pubKey^b) mod n
13^2 mod 15 = (1 • 4^1) mod 15  
169 mod 15 = 4 mod 15  
4 = 4 //passes the test
```

## My Question

In **Case 1**, the Verifier is actually checking that:

```
randNum^2 mod n = (randNum^2 mod n) mod n
```

which is essentially `randNum = randNum`

I don't understand why this part of the protocol is necessary. It seems that all the Prover has proved here is that they've picked a `randNum`. Anyone who doesn't know the `privKey` will always be able to do this.

I understand that there is only a 50% chance in any given round that this case will be chosen and that a false Prover (one who does not know `privKey`) will inevitably fail, but it seems that **Case 2**, where `b = 1`, is sufficient for the Verifier to be convinced that the Prover knows the `privKey` whilst gaining zero knowledge about the `privKey` **and** that no false Prover could pass this test.

Why is **Case 1** a necessary part of the protocol? I must be missing something.

I hope that's clear, Thanks!

Comment: I would also be very interested in this questions... does anyone know the answer? :)

Comment: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pollett/masters/Semesters/Fall13/akash/Zero_Knowledge_Proof.pdf

So point here is, if attacker can guess the b he can guess the x and break this.

Answer (score 2):

If $b$ was always the same value, you could convince the Verifier that you have the private key even though you actually don't!

Case $b = 1$:

Instead of sending $x = {\text{randNum}}^2 \bmod n$, the false Prover can send $x = {\text{randNum}}^2 / \text{pubKey} \bmod n$.

Assuming the Verifier sends $b = 1$, the false Prover can then send $\text{randNum} \bmod n$.

When the Verifier verifies the response, they check if ${\text{randNum}}^2 == (({\text{randNum}}^2)/\text{pubKey} \bmod n) \times \text{pubKey} \bmod n)$, which simplifies to ${\text{randNum}}^2 == {\text{randNum}}^2 \bmod n$, and that's obviously true. So even though the false Prover doesn't actually have the private key, the verification succeeded. But here's the catch: If $b$ turns out to be $0$ instead, they'd have to send $\sqrt{x} \bmod n$ in the final step. This is computationally infeasible.

As you observed, if the false Prover sends $x = {\text{randNum}}^2$ and $b$ turns out to be $0$, they can pass the verification. But if $b = 1$, the false Prover can't pass the final step, as they don't know $\text{privKey}$.

In summary, the false Prover has to commit to $b$ either being $0$ or $1$ before sending $x$. Each guess has a 50/50 probability of being correct. So after $t$ rounds, the chance of the Prover actually being a false Prover is $(1/2)^t$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. $MathJax/ \LaTex$ available in this site.